# Formatting a 3TB hard drive for media

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, fat32

I recently bought a 3TB internal SATA hard drive.

This drive is strictly for my Anime collection.

I want to use it to store my huge media (Video|Audio) collection. I don't have executables.

I don't want to format it in `NTFS` because of compatability issues with Linux.
I have constant power failures and end-up repairing NTFS partitions with Windows cos Linux can't fix the NTFS partitions.

`EXT4/EXT3` doesn't seem to have Windows support.

Fat32 seems to have only max 32 GB support. I'm not sure though.

I want a cross-platform format which will work without creating trouble on either OSes `(Linux & Windows)`.

Comment: Um... All Linux distros have supported NTFS for a very long time...

Comment: @Rahul2001 But my partitions get corrupted and I end up having to use Windows to repair them cos Linux can't.

Comment: The ext2 driver for windows always worked well for me. And as far as I can tell ext2 reads ext2+ just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to format it in NTFS because of compatability issues with Linux.

Today's modern GNU/Linux systems can mount, read, and write NTFS filesystems just fine.

> I have constant power failures and end-up repairing NTFS partitions with Windows cos Linux can't fix the NTFS partitions.

Repairing NTFS partitions with `chkdsk` from the Windows install media is a huge pain, yes. In my opinion, this sounds like yet another great reason to invest in an [uninterruptible power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

> I want a cross-platform format which will work without creating trouble on either OSes (Linux & Windows).

The filesystem which will most likely fit your particular use case is [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT). It supports large volumes with large individual file sizes, and it works on GNU/Linux, macOS, and Windows. However, the exFAT filesystem is **not journaled**. If you experienced corruption from power loss with NTFS, you'll likely experience it with exFAT as well.